# Automatic annotation for matlab plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, annotations

I have quite a few points plotted in a figure. I am now using annotation() function to add annotation in the same way for these points based on their locations. See [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603612/annotation-in-matlab-plot).

However they tend to mess up where the points are close to each other. Is there some function available to position the annotations as apart as possible?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but don't you specify exactly where to position the annotations?  Can't you manually offset those values?

Comment: Yes, I now specify not just the positions but the directions and lengths of the arrow and text. It will be nice if there is some way to auto determine directions and lengths of the arrows to make them apart, given the positions of the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function to automatically place text so that it doesn't overlap with anything on the [File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11466). Hopefully you can reverse engineer from there.